# zustand get initialState doesn't work although value exist in localStorage

Tags: javascript, zustand

I'm using zustand, here's my store. But the initialState is undefined, I wonder why. I checked my localStorage, it has

this

`{"state":{"selectedBrand":{"id":"1","label":"abc"}},"version":0}`

my store:

```
interface StoreState {
  selectedBrand: {
    id: string
    label: string
  }
}

export const useStore = create(
  persist<StoreState>(
    (set, get) => {
      const initialState = get()

      console.log('initialState', initialState)

      return {
        selectedBrand: initialState?.selectedBrand || {
          id: '',
          label: '',
        },
        setSelectedBrand: (newBrand: StoreState['selectedBrand']) =>
          set({ selectedBrand: newBrand }),
      }
    },
    {
      name: 'brand',
    }
  )
)
```

Comment: Check this:  https://docs.pmnd.rs/zustand/integrations/persisting-store-data